# Magento 2.2.0 Invalid Document Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.0, magento-upgrade

I am trying to **upgrade** a website from **Magento 2.1.8 to 2.2.0**

I have **configured composer for 2.2.0** and also updated it with command line.

Now when I run `magento setup:upgrade` its halt on running schema and showing following note: pfa for more info.

> Running schema recurring...Invalid Document Element 'resource': The
>   attribute 'title' is required but missing. Line: 12
>
> Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
>   Line: 13

[image]

Comment: Check link, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/setup-upgrade-error-invalid-document-element-resource-the-attribute-title-is-required-but-missing-magento-2/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My best guess is that you have a `<resource>`-tag in any `etc/acl.xml`-file with a missing `title`-attribute. Usually this would throw the issue that you could not create or edit a new role. I'm guessing that they created an extra check in 2.2 to detect this more earlier.

Better check the `acl.xml`-files of your own custom extensions and/or those of 3rd party extensions. Please note: the `title`-attribute is only required for new `<resource>`-nodes. So if your adding a new resource-node to an existing resource node (provided by another module) there is no need to add the `title`-attribute to those. For example:

```
<!-- provided by Magento_Backend, so they already have a title: -->
<resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
        <!-- provided by Magento_Config: -->
        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
            <!-- New resource! Title is required: -->
            <resource id="Vendor_Module::config_general" title="Something" translate="title"/> 
        </resource>
    </resource>
</resource>
```

Comment: some times this can happens when you are using a module that depends in other kind of parent module like a megaplaza core, and the parent module is not installed

Comment: I am also having the same issue, but unfortunately I was not able to find the etc/acl.xml file with missing title attribute, I have checked all custom extensions. Is there some way I can spot the file easily.

Comment: Any ideas on how to output the filename of the corrupt xml?

Comment: Installing the Mageplaza core fixed this issue for me: https://github.com/mageplaza/module-core

Answer (score 70):

To find the file with the missing attribute you can modify the following file

```
vendor/magento/framework/Config/Reader/Filesystem.php
```

add following code

```
foreach($configMerger->getDom()->getElementsByTagName('resource') as $element ){
    if (!$element->hasAttribute('title')) {
        var_dump($configMerger->getDom()->saveXML($element));
    }
}
```

to the method

```
protected function _readFiles($fileList)
```

so it should look like

```
protected function _readFiles($fileList)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Config\Dom $configMerger */
    $configMerger = null;
    foreach ($fileList as $key => $content) {
        try {
            if (!$configMerger) {
                $configMerger = $this->_createConfigMerger($this->_domDocumentClass, $content);
            } else {
                $configMerger->merge($content);
            }
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException $e) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase("Invalid XML in file %1:\n%2", [$key, $e->getMessage()])
            );
        }
    }
    if ($this->validationState->isValidationRequired()) {
        $errors = [];
        if ($configMerger && !$configMerger->validate($this->_schemaFile, $errors)) {
            foreach($configMerger->getDom()->getElementsByTagName('resource') as $element ){
                if (!$element->hasAttribute('title')) {
                    var_dump($configMerger->getDom()->saveXML($element));
                }
            }
            $message = "Invalid Document \n";
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase($message . implode("\n", $errors))
            );
        }
    }

    $output = [];
    if ($configMerger) {
        $output = $this->_converter->convert($configMerger->getDom());
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Now you will be able to see a dump of the wrong XML element.

Comment: Ah perfect, your solution saved me tons of time.. we're using a lot of third party extensions in our store :)

Comment: Perfect, you saved my time :) One of the 3rd party modules was referring a resource which wasn't defined.

Comment: You are a true hero

Comment: Great. I was able to debug the module that was causing the issue.

Comment: Amazing! You should work in Magento and help them sort this giant mess out ;)

Comment: Be careful, I upgraded my magento to 2.4.0v and I waste a lot of time trying to find one of my acl.xml files. At the end, the problem was in vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-api/etc/acl.xml

Comment: This helped me find the issue. We had all dotdigital extensions disabled and Dotdigitalgroup_Sms was automatically added and enabled in new version, so couldn't find parent id. After disabling *Dotdigitalgroup_Sms* error stopped.

Comment: Some time it return a null string so we can't know where the issue actually come from. If this solution not working, you guys can try Shaun Murray solution below. It's a fast workaround solution.

Comment: The script helps me solved the issue, thanks a lot for your help. Similar to Miguel, my issue also was because of vendor/magento/module-inventory-in-store-pickup-api/etc/acl.xml which is very strange as it is core Magento module, not our own code or extensions

Answer (score 17):

I had this same problem recently. A couple of observations and a workaround.

1) It would help immensely if instead of 'Invalid Document' it told you **which** document was invalid.

2) The setup:upgrade process should probably do some pre-flight checks to make sure it can do the upgrade.

Anyway, if you're stuck trying to find a missing title in the dozens of acl.xml files, but need to get a site back online quick, the quick workaround is to make the title attribute optional instead of required.

Edit vendor/magento/framework/Acl/etc/acl_merged.xsd

Find the line

```
<xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="required" />
```

replace with

```
<xs:attribute name="title" type="typeTitle" use="optional" />
```

re-run magento setup:upgrade

You'll still need to find the plugin with the missing title at some point.

Comment: That fixed it right up.
A million thankyous!!

Comment: I have spent all morning on this !! you are a legend

Comment: Useful for a quick fix on a local box

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @DimaPortenko, @GielBerkers and @ShaunMurray

You save lots of time to find an error in my ACL file.

After upgrade Magento 2.3.4 to 2.4.2 I was facing this error on admin login.
[image: error in acl syntex]

by putting @DimaPortenko code at

> vendor\magento\framework\Config\Reader\Filesystem.php

I found the wrong acl.xml file easily.

```php
foreach($configMerger->getDom()->getElementsByTagName('resource') as $element ){
    if (!$element->hasAttribute('title')) {
        var_dump($configMerger->getDom()->saveXML($element));
    }
}
```

By using this command you can easily find the file find.

```bash
grep -Rn 'resource id="MSP_SecuritySuite::config"' ./ --include=acl.xml
```

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the "Adminhtml" to "Backend" in below code then it works.

Resource tag Before change :

```
**<resource id="Magento_Adminhtml::admin">**
```

Resource tag After change :

```
**<resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">**
```

Final code as below.

**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Neo_Testing::testing" title="testing" sortOrder="100"/>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Document Element resource The attribute title is required in Magento 2x

[image]

It't is working,

http://code.wewebtech.com/invalid-document-element-resource-the-attribute-title-is-required-in-magento-2x/